# Stop send on invalid Input Box date entry

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I send email with this script. I added a date input box which will add the date in email subject line. If I give a wrong date it accepts and sends the email.

```
    Sub Send_Files()
    'Working in Excel 2000-2013
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
        Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim FileCell As Range
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim strDate As String

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

    strDate = InputBox("Insert date in format dd/mm/yy", "User date", Format(No(),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
    If IsDate(strDate) Then
    strDate = Format(CDate(strDate), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    MsgBox strDate
    Else
    MsgBox "Wrong date format"
    End if

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        For Each cell In sh.Columns("c").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("d1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Testfile" & strDate
            .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Display  'Or use Send
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Exit Sub` after the Msgbox line.  But move your EnableEvents and ScreenUpdating block after the test for a valid Date, or they won't get switched back when you exit.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, support.

Answer (score 0):

Exit Sub after the Msgbox line. But move your EnableEvents and ScreenUpdating block after the test for a valid Date, or they won't get switched back when you exit. –  Tim Williams